# передача данных с прокси по udp

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

В настройках прокси указываю ip своего приложения,
браузер отправляет запрос прокси серверу. Прокси сервер получает запрос на получение страницы и отправляет его через udp на другой комп:

```
def send_udp_message(message, address, port):
    """send_udp_message sends a message to UDP server

    message should be a hexadecimal encoded string
    """
    message = message.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
    server_address = (address, port)
    print("ok")
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        sock.sendto(binascii.unhexlify(message), server_address)
        while True:
         print("Ждем ответа")
         
         data, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        
         ss = binascii.hexlify(data).decode("utf-8")
         if ss == "ffffff":
             break
         sss = ss[82:]
         print(ss)
         base = bytearray.fromhex(sss).decode()
        # break
        # global test
        # test = test+sss
         
    finally:
        sock.close()

    return binascii.hexlify(sss).decode("utf-8")


def handler(conn, tunn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(40960)
        print(data)
        if data:
            tunn.sendall(data)
        else:
            break


def handle(conn):
    request = conn.recv(40960)
    #print(request)
    s = request
    base64_url = base64.b64encode(s)
    url = "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in base64_url.decode("UTF-8"))
    print(url)
    message = "AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 " + url +" 00 00 01 00 01"
    print(message)
    response = send_udp_message(message, "127.0.0.1", 60)
    print(response)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8085))
sock.listen(10)
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    _thread.start_new_thread(handle, (conn,))
```

Далее, на другом ПК я получаю запрос, выполняю его и хочу вернуть содержимое запрашиваемой страницы страницы обратно браузеру:

```
def handler(conn):
    print("start")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(40960)
        #print(data)
        if data:
        #    tunn.sendall(data)
            print(data)
        else:
            break

addr = (host, port)
udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind(addr)

while True:
 conn, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)

 url = str(conn)[50:][:-21] #выдернуть запрос
 message_bytes = base64.b64decode(url)
 request = message_bytes.decode('utf-8') # получили запрос 
 #вызвать функцию гет запроса
 r = request
 print(r)
 i = r.find(' ')+1
 j = r.find(' ', i)
 host, port = r[i : j].split(':')
 port = int(port)
 print(host)
 print(port)
 tunn = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
 tunn.connect((host, port))

 _thread.start_new_thread(handler, (tunn,))
```

все работает до  `print("start")`, дальше приходит пустой ответ. Т.е переменная `data = b''`

Что я делаю не правильно, можно ли такое вообще организовать?

Comment: Что-то непонятно ничего. Вполне может оказаться, что ошибка в функции `send_udp_message`, а вы её не показали. И вообще в этом коде никакого UDP не видно, в общем покажите [mcve]

Comment: я не показал код udp что бы не нагружать вопрос, идея такая, браузер через прокси передает http запрос на получение страницы, грубо говоря ссылку сайта, прокси сервер принимает ее отправляет по udp на другой ПК. Это все работает. Дальше я получаю ссылку и пытаюсь открыть сайт что бы передать его обратно прокси серверу...

Comment: Без минимального воспроизводимого примера помочь вряд ли получится

Comment: Дополнил вопрос